# why do we require to synchronize StringBuffer when its methods are already synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

In Java Docs it says, `StringBuffer`'s methods are `synchronized`. Then why do I still need to manually `synchronize` the `StringBuffer` in the example given in this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244677/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-join-and-synchronised?noredirect=1#comment42978257_27244677)

I read somewhere that it is not worthy of using `StringBuffer` over `StringBuilder` because it (StringBuffer) is slower than `StringBuilder`. In this way, these two are same like `Vector` and `ArrayList`.

But I was wondering, why do we call it (`StringBuffer` or `Vector`) a `Thread Safe` classes, when we still need to manually enclose them in `synchronized` block like in the example mentioned in above link.  Why can't I rely on them. Can anyone explain & clear my doubts.

**Is there any way to check StringBuffer is really a Thread Safe class.**

Answer (score 3):

The methods in `StringBuffer` are internally synchronised, which means that if two threads append a String to a buffer at the same time then the buffer won't interleave the strings; it will append one then the other.

The example you link synchronises itself on the string buffer instance, which is a totally different thing.

Comment: if I comment the `synchronized` block, then threads should not interfere each other during `setCharAt()` method. Isn't the `setCharAt()` method synchronized in `StringBuffer` class. But the scene is opposite i.e. threads do interfere during `setCharAt()`, when I comment `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this

```
synchronized(sb) 
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.println(i+" : "+sb.charAt(0));
        }
        sb.setCharAt(0, (char) (sb.charAt(0)+1));
    }
```

you are synchronizing entire block (ie when thread 1 uses this block no other thread should be used until completion of thread1)
If you remove synchronized , at any point of time thread1 may release the lock , so thread2 or thread 3 may change its data